# Refactoring Android Pin Screen code

Tags: java, android, refactoring

For my Android app, I'm writing a pin screen fragment. It has a number pad, and I need to add an event handler to all of them. This following code works, but it doesn't look nice. I've thought about creating an array of the buttons and looping through them to do this, but is there an even easier way in Java? Even the act of putting them in an array would require me doing something like `Button[] buttons = [button1, button2, button3, ... ]`

```
button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
button3.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
button4.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button5 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
button5.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button6 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
button6.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button7 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button7);
button7.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button8 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
button8.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button9 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button9);
button9.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);

button0 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button0);
button0.setOnClickListener(pinButtonHandler);
```

Any way to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the repeating two lines into a method like this:

```
void registerClickHandler(String buttonId, IHandler handler) {
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(id);
    button.setOnClickListener(handler);
}
```

Assuming your Handler interface / superclass is called IHandler and your ids are strings. Then the registration code would look like this:

```
registerClickHandler(R.id.button1, pinButtonHandler);
registerClickHandler(R.id.button2, pinButtonHandler);
// ...
```

It's not fancy, but you have to specify the mapping between button id's and handlers somewhere and this is relatively easy on the eyes and doesn't require too many keystrokes.